# NumberFormatException for RGB and HSV?

Tags: android, seekbar, numberformatexception

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SeekBar HueSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.HueSB);
        SeekBar SatSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SatSB);
        SeekBar ValueSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.ValueSB);
        SeekBar RedSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.RedSB);
        SeekBar BlueSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.BlueSB);
        SeekBar GreenSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.GreenSB);

        RedSB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new RGBChangeListener());
        GreenSB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new RGBChangeListener());
        BlueSB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new RGBChangeListener());
        HueSB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new HSVChangeListener());
        SatSB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new HSVChangeListener());
        ValueSB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new HSVChangeListener());

    }

    private class HSVChangeListener implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            SeekBar RedSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.RedSB);
            SeekBar BlueSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.BlueSB);
            SeekBar GreenSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.GreenSB);
            SeekBar HueSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.HueSB);
            SeekBar SatSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SatSB);
            SeekBar ValueSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.ValueSB);

            EditText RedET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RedET);
            EditText GreenET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.GreenET);
            EditText BlueET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.BlueET);
            EditText HueET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HueET);
            EditText SatET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SatET);
            EditText ValET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ValueET);

            TextView tvColor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color1TV);

            float[] hsv = new float[3];

            if(fromUser == true) {
                if (seekBar.equals(HueSB)) {

                    HueET.setText(""+progress);
                    hsv[0] = Float.parseFloat(HueET.getText().toString());
                    hsv[1] = Float.parseFloat(SatET.getText().toString());
                    hsv[2] = Float.parseFloat(ValET.getText().toString());
                    int color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
                    RedSB.setProgress(Color.red(color));
                    BlueSB.setProgress(Color.blue(color));
                    GreenSB.setProgress(Color.green(color));
                    RedET.setText(""+Color.red(color));
                    BlueET.setText(""+Color.blue(color));
                    GreenET.setText(""+Color.green(color));
                    tvColor.setBackgroundColor(color);

                } else if  (seekBar.equals(SatSB)) {
                    SatET.setText(String.format("%.2f", (progress * .01f)));
                    hsv[0] = Float.parseFloat(HueET.getText().toString());
                    hsv[1] = Float.parseFloat(SatET.getText().toString());
                    hsv[2] = Float.parseFloat(ValET.getText().toString());
                    int color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
                    RedSB.setProgress(Color.red(color));
                    BlueSB.setProgress(Color.blue(color));
                    GreenSB.setProgress(Color.green(color));
                    RedET.setText(""+Color.red(color));
                    BlueET.setText(""+Color.blue(color));
                    GreenET.setText(""+Color.green(color));
                    tvColor.setBackgroundColor(color);

                } else if (seekBar.equals(ValueSB)) {

                    ValET.setText(String.format("%.2f", (progress * .01f)));
                    hsv[0] = Float.parseFloat(HueET.getText().toString());
                    hsv[1] = Float.parseFloat(SatET.getText().toString());
                    hsv[2] = Float.parseFloat(ValET.getText().toString());
                    int color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
                    RedSB.setProgress(Color.red(color));
                    BlueSB.setProgress(Color.blue(color));
                    GreenSB.setProgress(Color.green(color));
                    RedET.setText(""+Color.red(color));
                    BlueET.setText(""+Color.blue(color));
                    GreenET.setText(""+Color.green(color));
                    tvColor.setBackgroundColor(color);

                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    private class RGBChangeListener implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser) {
            SeekBar RedSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.RedSB);
            SeekBar BlueSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.BlueSB);
            SeekBar GreenSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.GreenSB);
            SeekBar HueSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.HueSB);
            SeekBar SatSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SatSB);
            SeekBar ValueSB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.ValueSB);

            EditText RedET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RedET);
            EditText GreenET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.GreenET);
            EditText BlueET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.BlueET);
            EditText HueET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HueET);
            EditText SatET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SatET);
            EditText ValET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ValueET);
            TextView tvColor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color1TV);

            float[] hsv = new float[3];

            if(fromUser == true) {
                if(seekBar.equals(RedSB)) {
                    RedET.setText(""+progress);
                    int color = Color.rgb(Integer.parseInt(RedET.getText().toString()),Integer.parseInt(GreenET.getText().toString()), Integer.parseInt(BlueET.getText().toString()));
                    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
                    HueSB.setProgress((int)hsv[0]);
                    SatSB.setProgress((int)(hsv[1]*100));
                    ValueSB.setProgress((int)(hsv[2]*100));
                    HueET.setText(""+String.format("%.0f",hsv[0]));
                    SatET.setText(""+String.format("%.0f",hsv[1]));
                    ValET.setText(""+String.format("%.0f",hsv[2]));
                    tvColor.setBackgroundColor(color);;

                } else if (seekBar.equals(BlueSB)) {
                    BlueET.setText(""+progress);
                    int color = Color.rgb(Integer.parseInt(RedET.getText().toString()),Integer.parseInt(GreenET.getText().toString()), Integer.parseInt(BlueET.getText().toString()));
                    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
                    HueSB.setProgress((int)hsv[0]);
                    SatSB.setProgress((int)(hsv[1]*100));
                    ValueSB.setProgress((int)(hsv[2]*100));
                    HueET.setText(""+String.format("%.0f",hsv[0]));
                    SatET.setText(""+String.format("%.0f",hsv[1]));
                    ValET.setText(""+String.format("%.0f",hsv[2]));
                    tvColor.setBackgroundColor(color);


                } else if (seekBar.equals(GreenSB)) {
                    GreenET.setText(""+progress);
                    int color = Color.rgb(Integer.parseInt(RedET.getText().toString()),Integer.parseInt(GreenET.getText().toString()), Integer.parseInt(BlueET.getText().toString()));
                    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
                    HueSB.setProgress((int)hsv[0]);
                    SatSB.setProgress((int)(hsv[1]*100));
                    ValueSB.setProgress((int)(hsv[2]*100));
                    HueET.setText(""+String.format("%.0f",hsv[0]));
                    SatET.setText(""+String.format("%.0f",hsv[1]));
                    ValET.setText(""+String.format("%.0f",hsv[2]));
                    tvColor.setBackgroundColor(color);

                }


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

I get this error for both RGB and HSV seek bars

The Logcat errors:

HSV SeekBar error

```
04-30 16:26:19.913: E/InputEventReceiver(2094): Exception dispatching input event.
04-30 16:26:19.953: E/AndroidRuntime(2094): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 16:26:19.953: E/AndroidRuntime(2094): Process: cs2302.dabrams1.rgbhsvchooser, PID: 2094
04-30 16:26:19.953: E/AndroidRuntime(2094): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
04-30 16:26:19.953: E/AndroidRuntime(2094):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
04-30 16:26:19.953: E/AndroidRuntime(2094):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:289)
04-30 16:26:19.953: E/AndroidRuntime(2094):     at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
04-30 16:26:19.953: E/AndroidRuntime(2094):     at cs2302.dabrams1.rgbhsvchooser.MainActivity$HSVChangeListener.onProgressChanged(MainActivity.java:81)
```

RGB SeekBar error

```
04-30 16:26:29.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2114): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 16:26:29.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2114): Process: cs2302.dabrams1.rgbhsvchooser, PID: 2114
04-30 16:26:29.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2114): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
04-30 16:26:29.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2114):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
04-30 16:26:29.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2114):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
04-30 16:26:29.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2114):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
04-30 16:26:29.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2114):     at cs2302.dabrams1.rgbhsvchooser.MainActivity$RGBChangeListener.onProgressChanged(MainActivity.java:170)
04-30 16:26:29.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2114):     at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:91)
```

I'm not sure how to fix the problem. It's a formatting issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call `Integer.parseInt` or `Float.parseFloat` at your listeners, their argument sometimes is just empty string - `""`. What if you get inside the listener for the first time and `seekBar.equals(BlueSB) == true`, for example? In such a case `RedET` and `GreenET` have no any value yet. The solution is pretty simple: put some default value (for example, `0`) to all your `EditTexts` in `XML` layout.

Comment: Ok I saw that and I fixed it. Now it works and doesn't crash. Thanks for the help. Didn't think it would be something that simple.